# Is a Grails plugin overkill just for a bunch of utility classes

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a bunch of utility classes, that have nothing to do with web requests, database etc.  Very similar to POJOS, except they are never persisted.

I want to make these classes available to a number of Grails applications and plugins.

At the moment, I putting these classes in their own plugin.  It just seems like overkill.  In the java world they would just be one package that was jar'ed.

I want to use some of the Groovy annotations such as @immutable etc so I want to stay in Groovy.  But, I was wondering do I have any other options because a plugin, because that seems like overkill.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

technically seen, this would be a bit of overkill indeed.
On the other hand, you just need a single repository and build process to deploy your app. I think, a single dependency resolution system which in integrated in Grails is better than 2 or more, unless you have them already.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a plugin, or compile the Groovy into classes and make a jar that you share. Using annotations like @Immutable will work in classes from a jar or as source from a plugin.